# Guardar un objeto con una propiedad dinámica en mongo DB utilizando una web-api

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

Estoy intentando hacer una web api que guarda y recupera objetos en mongo en formato json, el problema es que uno de los objetos puede tener diferentes propiedades .

he intentado usar un objeto dynamic pero me encuentro con problemas.

Si tengo estos objetos:

```
{ "elements" : [
    {
        "type" : "logo", 
        "options" : {
            "align" : "center", 
            "padding" : [
                "10px", 
                "10px", 
                "10px", 
                "10px"
            ],              
            "alt" : "imagen 4", 
            "backgroundColor" : "#ffffff", 
            "width" : "230"
        }, 
        "_id" : "1234", 

}

        "type" : "imageTextNone", 
        "options" : {

            "backgroundColor" : "#ffffff", 
            "text" : "<span></span>", 
            "text1" : "ejemplo", 
            "text2" : "ejemplo", 
            "text3" : "ejemplo", 

        }, 
        "_id" : "i234", 

    }
],
```

¿Cómo podría guardarlos y recuperarlos sin tener que crear una clase options con todas las propiedades?

he probado un objeto dynamic en una clase similar a esta:

```
public class element {

public string type { get; set;}
public dynamic options { get; set;}
public string id { get; set; }


}
```

Entonces los elementos que ya tengo guardados en mongo son devueltos por la web api sin problemas. desserializa las options desde mongo y es devuelto por la web api sin problema. Pero al hacer una llamada a la api el element llega con el objeto options como object en lugar de un `ExpandoObject`

Answer (score 0):

La llamada ajax desde la web que lo llamaba, requería hacer un `JSON.stringify` al mensaje, consiguiendo así que la propiedad se rellenara.

Entonces dejó de funcionar la serialización a mongo. Por lo que la solución que encontré pese a no ser optima fue hacer un `.ToString();' a options para acabar guardando un string Json.

Answer (score -1):

La mejor opcion que veo es utilizar `Dictionary<string,string[]>` para options. Las db NoSQL son sin esquema(schemeless), lo que hace mas dificil utilizar con objetos fijos y utilizar `dynamic` para ese tipo de operaciones seria una sobrecarga muy grande por lo dinamicas que son estos tipos de db.

Comment: ¿Entonces, cómo haría la desserialización? Ahora solo tengo el problema de guardar un nuevo elemento. si lo cambio por un  'Dictionary<string,string[]>'  no funciona en ninguna dirección.